# ERC20 Token Creation: error says ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, transfer, import

I am running the following code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
   pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

   import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol"; //file 
   imported

   contract KaurCoin is ERC20 {
       constructor() ERC20("KaurCoin", "KaurCoin") {
           _mint(msg.sender,
   100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000);
       }
   }
```

When I check the balance of the address I deployed from, it gives me the Ether number specified in the code. However, when I try to transfer 1 wei from this address to another address I get the following error: ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance. How can I correct my code so that the second address receives wei? These functions are being imported from the ERC20 contract from Open Zeppelin.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly did you do? I followed your steps but it worked for me fine.

Comment: Your code is correct; I tried it on Remix. However, I believe you might be attempting to transfer from the wrong account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your given code works fine, if you are using Remix local environment make sure to switch back to the same account you deployed this contract from after copying the other account you want to transfer this amount to.

Comment: It appears I made a silly mistake not switching back to the account I want to transfer ether from. This worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Beata you are welcome, if it helped please consider accepting it as an answer.